# How do i pass the values of a multiselect dropdown component into my data array in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have setup a Register form function that has multiple entry fields, one of which is a multiselect dropdown component.

```
export default function Register() {
  const [data, setData] = useState({
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
    email: '',
    password: '',
    profileName:'',
    address:'',
    city:'',
    state:'',
    zip:'',
    phone:'',
    about:'',
    products:[],
    practices:[],
    buy: [],
    logo:'',
    featured:'',
    banner:'',
    terms:'',
  })
```

I have setup an empty array to take in the information.
Here is the code for the component in the page

```
<MultiselectProducts 
  name="products" 
  id="products" 
  multiple={true} 
  value={data.products} 
  onChange={(e) => setData({...data, products: e.target.value})} 
  />
```

I am trying to pass the selected items into the products array but am having trouble, how do i do it?
I can see from the the React component inspector on Chrome that the selected information is being held in a hook state:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGCcr.png)

But the selected information is not reaching the array.

Thanks!

Comment: what do you get back from `e.target.value`

Comment: I get each individual item displaying in state when selected but it overwrites the item each time, won't hold multiple items.